# Regular expressions in php deletes dots, commas, etc

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$words = ['mleko', 'masło'];
$words = explode(' ', $value); // create an array of words
foreach($words as $word) { //iterate through words
    $word = preg_replace('/[^\w]/uis', '', $word);
    if (in_array(mb_strtolower($word), $allergens)) {
        $return .= "<b>" . $word . "</b> ";
    } else {
        $return .= $word . " ";
    }
}
```

The above code works fine, but it deletes characters like:,. e.t.c.

How can I fix it? :)

Comment: you can define either blacklist (or whatever it calls now) or whitelist of chars, since now you're doing with whitelist - you could include needed chars in that set, something like [\w,;.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem jest w podejściu jakie zastosowałeś. Nie tylko w linii

```
$word = preg_replace('/[^\w]/uis', '', $word);
```

which should be extended with the characters of the Polish alphabet (the range of the `\w` class is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, remember to mention the range of lowercase and uppercase characters separately) like in this line

```
$word = preg_replace('/[^\wąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]/uis', '', $word);
```

Moreover, I believe that the above line is used incorrectly. In my opinion, you should save the result of this operation in another variable as below

```
$rawWord = preg_replace('/[^\wąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]/uis', '', $word);
```

Thanks to this, you have access to both the purified and the original value, which you can use in this way

```
if (in_array(mb_strtolower($rawWord), $allergens)) {
    $return .= str_replace($rawWord, "<b>{$rawWord}</b> ", $word);
} else {
    $return .= $word;
}
```

With this approach, however, you will still miss some characters. Even spaces that you filtered out with `explode` earlier. In my opinion, instead of concatenating a string, you should build an array and finally concatenate it with spaces. Complete code below.

```
$allergens = ['jogurt', 'jaja', 'żytni', "jogurt", "banan"];
$value = 'Chleb żytni, masło z mleka, jogurt naturalny z mleka, jaja, pieczeń rzymska z kaszą gryczaną.';

$returns = [];
$words = explode(' ', $value); // create an array of words
foreach($words as $word) { //iterate through words
    $rawWord = preg_replace('/[^\wąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]/uis', '', $word);
    if (in_array(mb_strtolower($rawWord), $allergens)) {
        $returns[] = str_replace($rawWord, "<b>{$rawWord}</b>", $word);
    } else {
        $returns[] = $word;
    }
}

$return = implode(' ', $returns);
```

Look at this line

```
$returns[] = str_replace($rawWord, "<b>{$rawWord}</b>", $word);
```

Replaces the original word (containing the characters you want to ignore) with cleaned and bold version of the word. This keeps all characters (like commas) stuck to the word.

In the `$return` variable at the end you will get something like this

> Chleb **żytni**, masło z mleka, **jogurt** naturalny z mleka, **jaja**, pieczeń rzymska z kaszą gryczaną.

Comment: I change my Code to: $allergens = ['jogurt', 'jaja', "żytni", "jogurt", "banan"]; $words = explode(' ', $value); // create an array of words In result I have: "Chleb żytni, masło z mleka,<b> jogurt</b> naturalny z mleka, <b>jaja</b>, Pieczeń rzymska z kaszą gryczaną". I Haven't <b> in "żytni". Why?

Comment: @terylo - Because ż is not in a-zA-Z ;) You have to use our national signs enumeratively. I updated my answer. You have to remember to enumerate lower and upper case separately.

Comment: it's not help :( I thing this problem is in this line: if (in_array(($word), $allergens))

Comment: Update your question then - add more data as input and show output and the output you expect.

Comment: @terylo - You marked my answer a little too quickly. In exchane for it, I updated my answer, prompting you with a complete code that should solve your problem;)